# Using a character to quit program

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

How do you use letter "X" to quit the program? I used key event with key char assigned for letter "X" to use as an exit key for mine but I really should use Key Listener, I just can't get it to work. Any tips or suggestions are much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class module1 extends Application {




Pane pane = new Pane();
double width = 400;
double height = 400;
double cX = width / 2;
double cY = height / 2;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case UP: moveUp(); break;
            case DOWN: moveDown(); break;
            case LEFT: moveLeft(); break;
            case RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, width, height));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Click to see position..");
    primaryStage.show();
    pane.requestFocus();
}

private void moveUp() {
    Line sLine = new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10);
    sLine.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    pane.getChildren().add(sLine);
    cY -= 10;

}



class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {                
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'x') {

            System.exit(0);
        }

        }
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);


    }


}
```

Comment: Don't use awt classes in JavaFX programs.

Comment: Where do you set the KeyHandler?

Comment: Ok thanks, why shouldn't I use that?

Comment: Because you're using JavaFX which is not compatible to awt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your AWT KeyEvent and add something like this to your stage:

```
stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(final KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.X)) System.exit(0);
    }
}
```